# Как взять определенную информацию из сообщения пользователя ботом вк?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Есть беседа в которой пишут объявления в которых указано для какой учебной группы это предназначено **(например `"41ПДО8301"`)**. Боту нужно в сообщении найти этот тэг и сохранить сообщение с тэгом этой группы в бд. Но вот вопрос, как заставить бота найти именно этот тэг? Нужен ли для этого `ИИ`?

Comment: А зачем вам ИИ. Вы можете получить все сообщение с тегом целиком?

Comment: @Amgarak Сообщение целиком могу получить, но нужно будет сделать сортировку с отметкой группы. То есть в бд будет создаваться строка с данными Сообщение|Тэг

Comment: Так в чем тогда проблема? Проверяйте каждое полученное сообщения на вхождение вашего тега, если он есть - добавляйте в бд else игнорируйте.

Comment: @Amgarak А как именно делать поиск этого тега? Указать все возможные в список и перебирать?

Comment: Да. А сам поиск можно как вариант делать через регулярные выражения.